# Primeng Datatable selection with weird data

Tags: json, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm retrieving two sets of data from an MSSQL server.
Set one: (which is user specific, so this set changes)

```
[
  {
    "TargetID": 1,
    "Enabled": true
  },
  {
    "TargetID": 2,
    "Enabled": true
  }
]
```

Set two:

```
[
  {
    "Platform": "BB",
    "ID": 1
  },
  {
    "Platform": "MDL01",
    "ID": 2
  },
  {
    "Platform": "MDLEX",
    "ID": 4
  }
]
```

Set two populates the Primeng Datatable. Set one's TargetID value refers to the ID in set two. Whenever the TargetID value is the same as the ID in set two, I have to check this in the Datatable.

The datatable:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <p-dataTable [value]="doelplatformen" [rows]="3" class="thumbnail" resizableColumns="true" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="0"
                [rowsPerPageOptions]="[3,5,10]" emptyMessage="Loading data" [(selection)]="selectedDoelplatformen" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelectDoelplatform($event)">
                <p-column [style]="{'width':'30px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
                <p-column [style]="{'width':'40px'}" field="ID" header="ID"></p-column>
                <p-column field="Platform" header="Platform"></p-column>
            </p-dataTable>
        </div>
```

I haven't tried much because I have no idea how this could be achieved? I can't even figure out how to hard code the selected rows...

Any help would be greatly apreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem is not clear to me. If TargetID from set-one is the same as the ID from set-two what exactly should happen then?

Comment: and where is your code for the Datatable?

Comment: Then the row with the same ID as TargetID should be selected. I'll update the question with the datatable code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map your `set1` to array of Ids which should be selected:

```
let selectedIds = set1.map(it => it.TargetID);
```

Then pick those `set2` records which Ids exists in that array:

```
this.selectedItems = set2.filter(inv => selectedIds.indexOf(inv.ID) != -1);
```

Use `selection` attribute of the table to select rows:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="items" [(selection)]="selectedItems">
...
</p-dataTable>
```

[Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/8oF2oUNXAnCJkSdwuIeG/)

Comment: This is perfect!!!! Thank you so much! This is my last week to finish this project for my thesis and this was the last thing I couldn't figure out :D You saved me!

Comment: If I pass an array to p-datatable, the items from array are not pre-selected. How does the table compares the selected array with the value array.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari, it compares row objects. If you need to compare by some field like id, you should use rowTrackBy property of the p-dataTable component.

Comment: @hiper2d Do you mean it compares an object to other object by comparing all the properties.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari, by default the answer is yes, but you can change this behaviour. Read the [documentation's](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable) 'Selection' section. It suggests to use some additional properties to prevent deepEquals comparison.